# 'permission denied' error with random getDownloadURL flutter/firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm writing an app which has user profiles in it. The user is allowed to take a photo or choose from their photo library.

Once the photo is taken, I use this function:

```
Future<String> uploadFile(File image, String directory, String imageName) async {
    assert(image.existsSync());
    StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('$directory/$imageName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(image);
    await uploadTask.onComplete;
    var dowurl = await storageReference.getDownloadURL();
    return dowurl.toString();
  }
```

to upload the image to firebase. The image appears in the Firebase storage area fine, and the URL is generated, and added to the user's profile as I've defined in the database.

The rules of firebase are set as follows:

**Database**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Storage**

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/myappname.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

which I believe should allow access for any user as long as they're authenticated (they are!)

I'm uploading the URLs generated by `uploadFile()` to the users profile, but about 1/6 of them gives a URL which, when accessed gives the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
}
```

I'm at a loss as to what is going on here, as the rest of the code works fine, and the 'choice' of file which causes the problem seems completely random.

The URLs generated have different token IDs at the end of each, but I'm not generating them - they're coming from the `getDownloadURL()` function. I'm keen to stress that the process is the same for each file, but for some reason, randomly, one of the generated URLs doesn't work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that the config (`google-services.json`/`google-services.info.plist`) on the devices that generate those broken URLs might be wrong/outdated?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How would I know? Flutter doctor returns ```no issues found``` and I've already tried 'run upgrade' on all the pub packages?

If I copy and paste the URLs generated into a browser, they all work aside from the ones that don't in the app. All the URLs look legitimate.

Comment: `flutter doctor` would not catch this, as it's an outdated Firebase config. If you can reproduce it somewhere, redownload the config for that app from the console, recompile/install and try again.

Comment: re-downloaded the google-services.info.plist/google-services.json, cleaned the build, recompiled everything, but still the same. Again, completely random as to which of the images was missing and permission denied. Also updated all the pod files in the app too.

Comment: Hmmm... I have no idea what's going on in that case. It might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, as they can compare the URL and token with your project data.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen - I have submitted a ticket to Firebase support.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - update. I've examined the URLs in the 'token' section of Firebase Storage on each of the images, and it seems that ```getDownloadURL``` is actually returning different tokens on the end of *some* of the URLs generated? No flaw in the code, as you can see above. The image is saved, the URL is immediately generated, stored, then uploaded as a string to Firebase Database. ‍♂️